# How did the Community user earn the Civic Duty badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, community-user

Apparently, [the Community user earned the Civic Duty badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty).

How the heck did that happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the profile, it has 755 votes as of right now, which is greater than the 300 required for the civic duty badge. How does it get these votes? In it's profile it says "Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted". I believe the community user may also own the votes (up and down) of accounts that no longer exist.

Comment: No longer relevant, the badges were all removed/hidden on SO/MSO by now.

Answer (score 5):

From it's [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community):

> I do things like
>
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that
>     get permanently deleted

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it! =P

Comment: That's only the downvotes, somehow it's gaining upvotes too.