# Community user badges on Sound Design and MathOverflow are not hidden like on all other sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, profile-page, community-user

The Community user has badges on [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity) and 
[MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/-1/community?tab=topactivity). 
While they are partially hidden, they are still visible, and they are also visible in the [awarded badges](https://mathoverflow.net/help/badges/12/strunk-white).

I guess this is partly because these sites have been imported in the SE network, not been created through the Area 51 process.

Comment: Why's that a bug?

Comment: @Mat, because the Community user isn't supposed to have any badges. They are suppressed in most places.

Comment: Why not? It even gets to wear hats: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/community-please-show-some-holiday-spirit

Comment: @Mat because Community doesn't earn badges by default.

Comment: @Mat the hats are temporary fun, badges are whole different story, and indeed should not exist.

Comment: Anyway, the reason is probably because those two sites are special: they didn't go through Area 51 like all others,  but were imported from existing, non-SE, sites.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I already said that in my post. However, ja.SO, ru.SO and rus.SE, which have also been imported, don't have the problem.

Comment: No, the localized versions of SO were not imported from external non-SE site as far as I know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Are you sure? ja.SO and rus.SE have no place on Area 51.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian for example.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You are right about that one. How about the others?

Comment: Well, they might have created them  based on SO "template" without a proposal, but still, pretty sure they did not import from any external site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6343/how-did-the-community-user-earn-the-civic-duty-badge

Comment: @Oded this fails to explain why it doesn't have those badges on all sites, as it should if it was really like any other user. Fact is, badges are removed/hidden on all sites, except on those two mentioned here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - they are removed on a schedule. I *think* it is a weekly one.

Comment: @Oded thanks, never suspected... this totally fits as an answer here then.

Comment: @Oded something still sounds off. If that was the case, we should have seen many more cases of badges earned, before being removed by the scheduled task. Just checked 10 random sites, no badges for Community in any of them. Any chance you can look deeper in the rabbit hole?

Comment: Besides, those badges were already awarded in 2011.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not that many people with votes get deleted, particularly not on smaller sites.

Comment: @Oded but other badges, like Editor?

Comment: @Oded, For your information, they still are there.

Comment: Well, it is a low priority bug/issue and is not hurting anything. Frankly, this is very low down on the list of things to fix.